# Swift How To - First/Where statement checking array of optional objects - unwrap and match

Tags: swift

I have an array of objects that are all of class `PFObject`.
I have a subclass of `PFObject` called `GameCategory` where some of the `PFObject`s in my array are `GameCategory`.

I was wondering how to write a first/where statement that would check each object to see if it is of class GameCategory, then check for a matching ID.

Here is my non-working attempt to do this:

```
for id in Ids {
    if let object = self.matchObjects.first(where: {
        if let gameCategory = $0 as? GameCategory {
            gameCategory.id == id
        }
    }) {
        //object successfully cast as GameCategory, and the GameCategory id was a match            
    }
}
```

This code returns the error 'Missing return in a closure expected to return 'Bool'.

Comment: The `where` closure must return a `Bool` value, what the error clearly says. What are you going to accomplish? At the moment it seems that the `id` of the first found `GameCategory` instance is overwritten in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing the return in that `first(where:` closure and casting as `GameCategory` (your cast is only existing in the scope of that closure). I wrote it a little bit different but it will achieve the same:

```swift
for id in Ids {
    if let object = self.matchObjects.first(where: { ($0 as? GameCategory)?.id == id }) as? GameCategory {
        //object cast as GameCategory and the id was a match
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be some syntax issue.